# Modular relations between objects

Tags: java, android, relationship, modularity

I am developing multiple android applications that share parts of the same data models. Those models have relations between each other but not every model is included in every application.
To keep the application's build as small as possible I do not want references to a model I do not use in the application.

For example imagine a cat that has an owner and a toy. Currently the class would look like this:

`class Cat {
    public Owner getOwner() {...};
    public Toy getToy() {...};
}`

Now in application `A` I only want to display things about a cat and it's owner and in application `B` things about a cat and it's toys.

Coming from JavaScript I would just inject the methods to the Cat class before it's usage but since it's Java here this doesn't seem to be possible.

So is there a way to achieve modular dependencies between those objects?
When answering please keep in mind that my goal is to minimize the android build, so large shiny libraries are not a desired solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance,
McFarlane

Comment: Why don't you just include the basic model in your application and only use the fields which you need? That shouldn't be a problem at all. What you can also do is build a new project with all the models inside it and use a dependency in your application to use your models.

Comment: Wouldn't the Toy class still be compiled into the binary even if I only use cat.getOwner()?

Comment: Yes, but the overhead for such small text files is minimal.

Comment: But in case of Android it counts against the 65536 method reference limit. And the example I gave is just to visualize the problem. Our actual model structure is much more complex.